# cp: cannot stat ‘build/docker/gotools/bin/protoc-gen-go’: No such file or directory

Tags: vagrant, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I try to build **hyperledger fabric**, and have installed the project as the guide in http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#option-1-vagrant-development-environment.

When I try to 'make peer', command is shown as:

> vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/devenv$
>   cp: cannot stat 'build/docker/gotools/bin/protoc-gen-go': No such file
>   or directory

I looked into the folder and didn't find the file `protoc-gen-go`. Does it indicate that I missed few steps when I was setting up the envrionment?

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Run

```
$go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

Download protoc-gen-go

Step 2: cp

```
$ cp $GOPATH/bin/protoc-gen-go build/docker/gotools/bin/
```

Then continue your make.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the file `protoc-gen-go` in path: `$GOPATH/bin`, then copy this file to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/docker/gotools/bin/`.
If all things has done, you can run: `make peer` and it will work.

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `peer'.  Stop.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. Maybe your GOPATH and GOROOT variables are conflicted with your customized paths.

I solved the problem like this:

- Delete /usr/lib/go
- Delete /usr/local/go
- Download protoc-gen-go ($go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go)
- protoc-gen-go binary is created at your go workspace
- copy the protoc-gen-go binary to fabric/build/docker/gotools/bin/
- BUILD AS make peer

I hope this would helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to:

```
cd /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/
make peer
```

and see if it works? Looks like you are in the devenv subdir.

Comment: actually the environment I set up is based on windows, Im not sure if the command you provided could be valid. And would you mind telling me in which path do you execute the command 'make gotools'?

Comment: looks like you use ubuntu 14.04 on vagrant. That should work just the same. I executed the command in /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/

Comment: -bash: cd: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when Docker was returning permissions issues causing the build to fail.

Once that happens, the build process won't work successfully even after you fix the Docker issues.

Instead, once Docker is repaired, delete the gotools folder and run `make` again:

```
Makefile:245: recipe for target 'build/docker/gotools' failed
make: *** [build/docker/gotools] Error 126
user@:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ rm -rf build/docker/gotools/
user@:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ make all
```